# push уведомления через push.world

Tags: javascript, push-уведомления

Для своего сайта решил использовать сервис push.world. Проблема заключается в подписке. Сначала сайт показывает виджет от сервиса в котором заготовленное мной предложение и кнопка Подписаться. При нажатии кнопки Подписаться появляется браузерное диалоговое окно, которое запрашивает разрешения получения уведомлений или их блокировки. Так вот, есть ли возможность не вызывать браузерное диалоговое окно, а сразу в первом, при нажатии кнопки Подписаться, уведомления автоматически разрешались? На крайний случай, есть ли вариант убрать виджет от сервиса и сразу показывать браузерное диалоговое окно, но сервис не дает такой возможности. Короче, нужно только одно окно для подтверждения получений уведомлений.